# Snap not working at all in Blender 3.0.0

Tags: modeling, snapping

I need to move the edge vertices of an open semi-spherical mesh to another large mesh, a short distance away, so as to end up with a properly closed single mesh for 3D-printing purposes. I am trying to move vertices using snapping to a face as suggested in Fig 1.
[image: Fig 1. Snap vertex to face]
I thought that turning on Snapping, setting Snap-to-Face parameters, Proportional Edit off, and then Moving the separated vertices to the other-mesh faces would be the answer -- a 10-minute edit. Now, two and a half days later, after looking at every Answer, tutorial and web page I could find on Snapping, I am still dead in the water and desperate for help.

I have replicated the situation with a sloped cube and open-ended cylinder as in Fig 2 which shows the Snap settings. (I flipped one target face, in case Normals were causing the problem, but no difference in behaviour.)
[image: Fig 2]
No matter what Snap-to-Face setting I used in Edit Mode, G X-moved vertices would not Snap to anything on the cube: Fig 3.
[image: Fig 3]
Hitting Ctrl or A during Move made no difference,
I also tried snapping vertices to another object (with the same Snap-to-Face settings), but again nothing. I closed and re-opened Blender. Same.

Finally, I realized that, in spite of the Snap button being ON, Blender never showed the little yellow circles around vertices to confirm that it was operating in Snap mode.
Is this a Blender 3.0.0 issue or am I doing something wrong?

---

@mqbaka, indeed, the two unconnected meshes are within one object in Edit mode and Snapping is needed to connect them.

And, yes, I had started with Project onto Self setting, but the results were rather peculiar and not what I expected for a G X move.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Blender 3.0.1 is the latest. Please upgrade and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: Blender 3.0.1 behaves in the same way.

Comment: To move forward,  could someone please create an example like this  that demonstrates Vertex Snap to Face within an Object working correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload the blend file? Taking a look to it would help with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your screenshot, I'm guessing that the cube and the cylinder are part of one object, in which case **you should enable `Project Onto Self`** :

[image]

Without this option, the snap will only occur to surfaces from other objects. Look at the screenshot from the tutorial and you'll see that it's a different object.

Also another hint to that is the fact that the yellow circle doesn't display. The yellow circle is there to indicate that Blender "found" a snap target to snap your vertices to. In your case, the yellow circle missing just means that no snapping target was found since `Project onto Self` was disabled so Blender didn't consider the object itself to be a snap target.